# How to retrieve a Character for a boolean field in SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to retrieve data from a 2005 version of SQL Server. The program that is calling the Stored Procedure if populating a datagridview in VB 2008. One of the fields coming back is a Boolean field. I bind the grid to a datatable but I don't want the Boolean value. I want to come back with Y for true and N for false. The Boolean field in below query is the inventory.active field

```
    SELECT      inventory.inventory_id, equipment.description, 
            inventory.sale_date, 
            inventory.warranty_date, inventory.extended_warranty_date, 
            inventory.location,inventory.serial_number, inventory.IP_address, inventory.printer_name,  inventory.active
```

I have tried iif(inventory.active,'Y','N') but doesn't accept it when try to excecute Sproc.

What is correct syntax for this. I have also attempted Case statement but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `boolean` data type in SQL Server; numbers of some sort are often used.  Presumably, you want a `case` expression.  I would guess:

```
(case when inventory.active = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end)
```

Although it has no relevance to your question, you should upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server.  SQL Server 2005 is years beyond the end of its life.

Comment: A `varbinary(1)` (though why you would use a `varbinary` and not a `binary` for that) @Hogan could have values from `0x0` to `0xF`; it's not the same as a Boolean. The closest to a Boolean in SQL Server is a `bit`; which can have the value `0`, `1`, and `NULL`. A `bit` cannot be used as a boolean operator though. `DECLARE @b bit = 1; SELECT 1 WHERE @b;` would result in an error

Comment: @larnu -- exactly right I was thinking of the `bit` type, which is like a boolean.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Thought I had tried that but I must not have had it correct. And yes the field is not a Boolean but is a bit. so Thanks Larnu